# Redirect to controller - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, controller

I have many views in a folder in views folder, for example in views/admin folder.

[image: This is a users view in admin folder, so the url is <code>localhost/file-sharing/admin/users</code>]

When I code

```
if (!empty($users->users)):
    foreach ($users->users as $user) {
          $link = site_url('ContentController/showActivities/' . $user->id);
           $what = $user->banned == 0 ? 'b':'u';
           $banned_t = $user->banned == 0 ? 'Banned':'Un-banned';

           echo '<tr id="user_'.$user->id.'">';
           echo '<td><div class="userimg"><img src="' . $user->profile_pic->medium . '"></div></td>';
           echo '<td>'.$user->name . '</td>';
           echo '<td>';
           echo $user->last_login == '' ? 'never' : $user->last_login;
           echo '</td>';
           echo $user->banned == 0 ? '<td><span class="label label-success">Active</span></td>' : '<td><span class="label label-danger">Banned</span></td>';
           echo '<td>'.$user->email.'</td>';
           echo '<td><div class="btn-group">
                          <button type="button" onclick="Buckty.user.edit($(this));"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editUser" data-id="'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                          </button>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a onclick="javascript:ref('.$user->id.')">Show Activities</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="Buckty.user.ban($(this));" data-id="'.$user->user_hash.'" data-what="'.$what.'">'.$banned_t.'</a></li>
                            <li><a onclick="Buckty.user.remove($(this));" data-id="'.$user->id.'">Delete</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div></td>';
           echo '</tr>';
    }
endif;
```

And this is the code that i want to redirect to controller

```
<li><a onclick="javascript:ref('.$user->id.')">Show Activities</a></li>
```

Javascript:

```
function ref(id) {
    window.open('ContentController/showActivities/'+id, '_blank');
}
```

But, when i click "Show Activities" menu, it always redirect to `http://localhost/file-sharing/admin/ContentController/showActivities/1` and it doesn't redirect to `ContentController/showActivities` controller. It should redirect to that controller if the url is `http://localhost/file-sharing/ContentController/showActivities/1`

Anybody know what should I do in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ref` where u define?

Comment: in js function.

Comment: `console.log(id)` and check id is empty or not.

Comment: id isn't empty.

Comment: actually `window.open('ContentController/showActivities/'+id, '_blank');` this will start from your base_url, your admin base_url is change right

Comment: just suggestion or hint for debugging: `window.open('http://localhost/file-sharing/ContentController/showActivities/'+id, '_blank');` try this, if its work than you need to define your admin base_url with different name maybe..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Being Owner` of this platform. Let me clear you few things. Site url is not being defined by `base_url()` or `site_url()` for functions and compatibility reasons.

First of all , i would not recommend you to not use controller names , try to organise and make routes for your controllers inside `routes.php` but now let's talk about your problem.

`site_url()` is your current url you are on. But you have very simple access to global settings for everything.

Introduction to global variables

- **$user**  || this contains currently logged in user's data , you can use it anywhere inside views
- **$this->current_user** || this contains similar data to above variable , but this should be used for controllers.
- **$site** || this contains site settings , every site settings data you have saved in database (from site_url to ads settings )
- **$site->site_url** || this is how you use your site url inside this platform
- **$this->site** || this should be used inside controllers to fetch site settings

so according to your problem , you should be using `$site->site_url` and not `site_url();`

basically change this :

```
$link = site_url('ContentController/showActivities/' . $user->id);
```

to this

```
$link = $site->site_url.'ContentController/showActivities/' . $user->id;
```

or if we talk about javascript then global variable for javascript is also there. you should be using `site_url` as site link so edit the below :

```
function ref(id) {
    window.open('ContentController/showActivities/'+id, '_blank');
}
```

to this

```
function ref(id) {
    window.location.replace(site_url + 'ContentController/showActivities/'+id, '_blank');
}
```

here is introduction to global variables for javascript :

- `site_url` || this contains your site url (from site settings )
- `user_data` || this contains current user's data (everything only password is not there )
- `site_info` || this contains site settings data.
- `tran` || this contains multi language translations
- `current_folder` || this contains current folder's hash id , on which you are currently

  - `current_folder` is 0 if it's on root folder , else it if `folder` if it's on un-functional view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function ref(id) {
    window.open('<?php echo base_url()?>ContentController/showActivities/'+id, '_blank');
}
```